# How can I Check if String is in an Array in a specific Firestore document (Swift)?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**What I want to do:** Check if a user is following another user. Basically I want to see if the UID of the user is in the "follower" array in the document of the other user-profile.

[image: It looks like this]

I thought of the option to use the `.whereField` command, but then I would get more documents and not only the one that I care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with array-contains operator:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

So you can write something like this:

```
usersRef
    .whereField("followers", arrayContains: "l47GVBdjsabjdjds")
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the user document (using whereField isEqualTo)and check if the followers field array contains the uid of the second user.